# Is there a precise open specification for the peercoin protocol?

Tags: specification, peercoin

I searched for an open specification of the peercoin protocol (more precise than the white paper) and I couldn't find one. Is it possible to find something similar to the bitcoin protocol specification available on bitcoin wiki but for peercoin ?

Answer (score 1):

Since most crypto-currencies are a fork of Bitcoin, you can get nitty gritty technical details from the Bitcoin wiki, specifically from [the technical category](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category%3aTechnical).

Say you want to know the specifications for communication, the [Protocol Specification](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification) article will help you out with how packets should be formatted down to the bit. It will have all sorts of details on things like [how to calculate difficulty](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty) or [what a block chain is](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_chain).

Peercoin share a lot of concepts with Bitcoin and thus *most* Bitcoin wiki articles will apply. Peercoin concepts such as its Proof-of-Stake may not be found in the Bitcoin wiki so refer to the whitepaper for differences.

Comment: Yes but I was wondering if there was something more precise than the whitepaper on the proof-of-stake used in peercoin. But it doesn't seem there is then

Answer (score 1):

This is old and the wiki is being redone but I used this when dev'ing peercoin related projects. 
http://wiki.peercointalk.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

You could treat the code as a precise specification of sorts. Eg: https://github.com/peercoin/peercoin/blob/master/src/kernel.cpp#L426

Its pretty terrible that they don't have a well-written spec for peercoin. It [never really caught on](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/peercoin/) tho, so not a whole reason to delve that deeply into it. There are better PoS designs these days if you're looking for ideas.